# Embed font awesome icon to external css file

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, icons, font-awesome

How to embed Font Awesome icon to external css style sheet.

For Font Awesome 5 & free icon---

```
#preview .buttons .ok {
    border: 1px solid #F5F5F5;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    font-size: 20px;

}
.ok:before {
    content: "\e900";
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

Now try it..

Comment: how are you importing font awesome? Can you replicate your problem in a code snippet ?

Comment: what version of font awesome?

Comment: @לבנימלכה version 4.3

Comment: @AravindS i don't know how to put

Comment: show mean the link of font awesome

Comment: @לבנימלכה yes i already include font awesome in my html file.

Comment: what kind of icon?? `\e900` does not exsit

Comment: oops i don't know i just copy that from my css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\e900` does not exist in font awesome's icons...

It works good with other(like `\f2b9`)

See here the icons and copy unicode to css :https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery

And put the link as below in your `head` tag

```css
#preview .buttons .ok {
    border: 1px solid #F5F5F5;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    font-size: 20px;

}
.ok:before {
    content: "\f2b9";
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-O8whS3fhG2OnA5Kas0Y9l3cfpmYjapjI0E4theH4iuMD+pLhbf6JI0jIMfYcK3yZ" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div id='preview'>
    <div class='buttons'>
          <div class='ok'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help!

Answer (score 1):

For Font Awesome 5 & free icon---

```
border: 1px solid #F5F5F5;
border-radius: 4px;
width: 28px;
height: 28px;
font-size: 20px;



content: "\e900"; 
display: inline-block; 
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
font-weight: 700;
font-size: inherit;
text-rendering: auto;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
transform: translate(0, 0);
```

Note: For font awesome 5 free icon this tag must be added on your external css file.

Now try it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to include Font Awesome , you need to include `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-O8whS3fhG2OnA5Kas0Y9l3cfpmYjapjI0E4theH4iuMD+pLhbf6JI0jIMfYcK3yZ" crossorigin="anonymous">` on your html file then use it to css . Take a look to official , docs about font awesome .